# High resolution screen on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, resolution, display

I have an Asus ZenBook Laptop with a 3200 x 1800 touchscreen, i tried enlarge icons but the ArcToolBox and other icons not fit on a 13.3 inches display. 
Other "more common" apps that do not have much problem.
How to get the best configuration?
Sorry for my english.

[image]

Comment: There have been several threads on the ESRI Forums on this.  This one refers to the other threads: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/170386.  There are several suggestions in these threads that you might try, but there is no generally accepted solution as noted in MaryBeth's answer.  ArcGIS Pro scales better than ArcMap.

Comment: struggling with the same issue :(

Answer (score 6):

There is now a solution to using ArcMap with high dpi screens at least on Windows 10. Install the Windows 10 Creators Update then change the settings on the ArcMap executable as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Per ESRI Troubleshooting page](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/164476) this has been reported as an issue and still in effect as of November. It appears contacting ESRI support is your best bet.

> Donald, this issue appears to be most likely related to an Enhancement
> which we have already reported to our developers.  The Enhancement is
> related to laptops that use a display adaptor that supports a 3200 X
> 1800 resolution or higher, and has been reported for several different
> laptops which have this adaptor.
>
> The Enhancement is currently listed
> as the following...
>
> NIM100282 -The Lenovo Yoga 2 has a display
> adapter which supports a 3200 x 1800 resolution, and ArcGIS for
> Desktop's icon's and text are skewed in this resolution.
>
> I
> understand that this is not your exact laptop, however, there are
> several cases in which different laptops with comparable resolution
> have been added.
>
> I would recommend contacting Esri Support so that
> we can create a case for you and add it to the existing Enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a solution to this problem with an older version of windows 10 (can't upgrade to Creator)

1) First follow the instructions here but apply to ArcMap.exe

https://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/

2) Then change the settings on the ArcMap executable so that none of the options are selected

[image: Arcmap Properties]

Now ArcMap will appear normal!